# I am making a project for multiple users and specific database for each user. Whenever a user access the url, specific database will connect (laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am making a project for multiple users and specific database for each user. Whenever a user access the url, specific database will connect for that user and some other user can also access the project but for that another database will connect.
How to achieve this in single laravel project?
I am using this code but every time I have to call "php artisan config:clear" and "php artisan server"

```
          Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
                       "host" => "...",
                       "database" => "...",
                       "username" => "...",
                       "password" => "..." 
          ]);
```

Comment: My advice: Don't do this. Make a proper multi-tenant application. Maintaining *N* independent database is a complete nightmare and may come to ruin you.

Comment: There are ways of defining [multiple database connections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-multiple-database-connections) but I'm not sure how that applies to Eloquent on a per-request basis.

Comment: Thankyou, I will learn how to make multi-tenant application.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, make a multi-tenant & multi-database system, I prefer Tenancy package for laravel to achieve this.